# intellij code formatting does not indent correctly after a method parameter return (kotlin & Java)

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, code-formatting

We have some trouble with how the code formatting works when returning after a method parameters call that is not correctly aligned with the above `)`. In AndroidStudio 3.2.1 currently but it was doing that for as far I can remember. The problem is happening in Kotlin and Java.

What the AutoFormat does that we don't like.

```
fun behaviourExample() {
    this.methodCall(
        lambda1 = { /*something*/ },
        lambda2 = { /*somethingElse*/ }
    )
        .map { "Line incorrectly indented" }
        .map { "I'd like the lines to be correctly indented" }
}

fun methodCall(lambda1: () -> Unit, lambda2: () -> Unit): String {
    return "otherThing"
}
```

We would like to find the parameters to change the AutoFormat like this: `map{}` correctly aligned with the closing `)`

```
fun behaviourExample() {
    this.methodCall(
            lambda1 = { /*something*/ },
            lambda2 = { /*somethingElse*/ }
        )
        .map { "Line correctly indented" }
        .map { "I'd like the lines to be correctly indented" }
}
```

What we are doing in the meanwhile is to return before the `methodCall`, that's not pretty but that works.

```
fun behaviourExample() {
    this
        .methodCall(
            lambda1 = { /*something*/ },
            lambda2 = { /*somethingElse*/ }
        )
        .map { "Line correctly indented but I don't like to be forced to add methodCall() in a new line" }
        .map { "I'd like the lines to be correctly indented" }
}
```

We suspect that it should be somewhere in the preferences -> Code Style -> Kotlin but we played with a bunch of parameters and didn't found it

[image: AndroidStudio Preferences Code Style]

Above is an example of how the autoformat behaves but our problem is with calls like `Single.zip()`, `Observable.concat()` etc... The indentation misleads where in the chain you can be. So we use it like this.

```
Single
    .zip (
        /* parameters */
    )
    .map { /* something */ }
```

Instead of

```
Single.zip (
        /* parameters */
    )
    .map { /* something */ }
```

Thanks for any help or leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting you're using now is actually how such code is supposed to be formatted according to the [coding conventions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html). If the closing parenthesis of a method call is wrapped to a new line, it's aligned with the beginning of the method call. There is no option to indent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: We will make a return in this case to avoid reading errors. Sad :(

Comment: `ktfmt` formats it the way the op is expecting. unfortunate that there is no setting to control it in IDE.